# Set Id Attribute of element to variable from directives controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Update #2:**
Sometimes using `template: '<div id="{{vm.divId}}"></div>'` works fine and the variable is input into the template and other times it doesn't work and instead of using the variable the ID is set to `id="{{vm.divId}}"`. I still haven't figured out what is making it work sometimes and not others

### Original Post

I have a simple directive that needs an element in the template to have the ID set dynamically. I figured this would be simple but no matter what I do the variable doesn't interpolate.

I have tried setting the ID like this, `template: '<div id="{{vm.divId}}"></div>'` like this `template: '<div ng-attr-id="{{vm.divId}}"></div>` and a number of variations of the two but none seem to work.

Here is the directive:

```
.directive('gMap', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'options': '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: function(mapService) {
            console.log(this.options.mapId); // This logs the specified ID
            this.divId = this.options.mapId;
        },
        template: '<div id="{{vm.divId}}"></div><div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
})
```

**Update:**
I cut and paste my code into plunkr and it works fine there so it must be something else outside this directive but I have no idea where to start

Comment: What do you actually see in your element?

Comment: @Phil I see this `<div id="{{vm.divId}}"></div>`

Comment: No errors in your console? It's unlikely you'll get an answer if you've already determined the cause of the problem is unrelated to the code in your question

Comment: There were no errors but it works now. No idea why it wasn't working before or what caused it to start working but I tried again today and everything's fine.

Comment: and now it isn't working again